# My getFrequency method for a doubly linked list implementation of a bag

Tags: java

I'm doing a doubly linked list bag implementation for a class so any hints to lead me in the right direction would be awesome

Here's some test code:

```
// Adding strings
  String[] contentsOfBag = {"A", "D", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"};
    testAdd(aBag, contentsOfBag);

  // Tests on a bag that is not empty
  testIsEmpty(aBag, false);
  String[] testStrings2 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "Z"};
  testFrequency(aBag, testStrings2);
  testContains(aBag, testStrings2);
```

When the frequency is tested after ABCDZ, this comes up:

```
Testing the method getFrequencyOf:
In this bag, the count of A is 7
In this bag, the count of B is 5
In this bag, the count of C is 3
In this bag, the count of D is 6
In this bag, the count of Z is 0

Testing the method contains:
Does this bag contain A? true
Does this bag contain B? true
Does this bag contain C? true
Does this bag contain D? true
Does this bag contain Z? false
```

Here's the testGetFrequency:

```
private static void testFrequency(BagInterface<String> aBag, String[] tests)
{
    System.out.println("\nTesting the method getFrequencyOf:");
  for (int index = 0; index < tests.length; index++)
     System.out.println("In this bag, the count of " + tests[index] + 
                        " is " + aBag.getFrequencyOf(tests[index]));
}
```

We aren't supposed to edit the test class, all we're doing is writing the methods.

and here is my getFrequencyOf method:

```
public int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry) {
    Node current = head;
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        if(current.data.equals(anEntry))
            result++;
        else
            current = current.next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to advance to the next entry, whether you found a match or not:

```
public int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry)
{
    Node current = head;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        if (current.data.equals(anEntry)) {
            result++;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ahh of course, so simple. I should've caught that. Thank you. But there is just one more thing I'm having trouble with. Shouldn't getFrequencyOf be testing ABCDZ not ADBACAD? When I run the code now it says `In this bag, the count of A is 3
In this bag, the count of B is 1
In this bag, the count of C is 1
In this bag, the count of D is 2
In this bag, the count of Z is 0`

Comment: The contents of the "bag" are `ADBACAD` and the `getFrequencyOf` method is counting the number of times that `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `Z` are in that "bag." Based on my understanding of the test and your code, I believe the output you are seeing is correct.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I feel a bit dumb, but I definitely get it now. Thanks again for your help.